# Spring, @WebService / @WebMethod, (using Jax-WS), receiving a serialized object?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, serialization, jax-ws

I've been gradually piecing together how I can receive a serialized object within Spring and have gotten a web service working, by following a tutorial, that uses Jax-WS. I have verified that I can access this basic service through a browser by pulling up the XML page using a url like `http://localhost:8080/WebServicesExample/hello?wsdl`

The code I currently have is like below, however I want to make a service so that a serialized object can be passed in, for example a HashMap and then have spring de-serialize it, etc. I have been doing a lot of reading on this but am still a bit lost, I would appreciate if anyone can offer advice how to get from where I am at currently to what I am trying to do. Thanks

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.mkyong.bo.HelloWorldBo;

@WebService
public class HelloWorldWS{

    //DI via Spring
    HelloWorldBo helloWorldBo;

    @WebMethod(exclude=true)
    public void setHelloWorldBo(HelloWorldBo helloWorldBo) {
        this.helloWorldBo = helloWorldBo;
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName="getHelloWorld")
    public String getHelloWorld() {

        return helloWorldBo.getHelloWorld();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not completely sure which WS stack you have used for exposing this service, assuming that you just want to create a JAX-WS based sample, let me point you to a working sample that I had created earlier available at : `git://github.com/bijukunjummen/memberservice-codefirst.git` .

This sample uses Apache CXF as the JAX-WS implementation, and uses JAXB2 for binding (converting the incoming xml to Java objects and back)

In your example, Apache CXF would allow you to expose a WS interface using an entry into spring configuration files of the type:

```
<jaxws:endpoint address="/helloworldservice" id="helloworld" implementor="#helloworldBean" >
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Comment: Thanks, ok so I guess I should use the process where I convert a Java object to XML, I will take a look at the sample

Comment: Cool, I found your blog post on it and checkout the code, looks like this will be a big help, so from what I understand, from briefly looking over the code, it is the `MemberDetailsRequest` (in your sample) class that is being passed in and returned back out by the service

Comment: Yes Rick, you should be able to run the sample using mvn jetty:run. Once you have it running, the endpoint will be at http://localhost:8080/memberservice-codefirst/webservices/memberservice and the wsdl for the service at http://localhost:8080/memberservice-codefirst/webservices/memberservice.wsdl. You can send a request to it using a tool like SOAPUI, which can generate a sample request for you given the wsdl file.